# How can I debug intermittent high pings?

Tags: wireless, networking

Recently my browsing and gaming (CCS) experience has been disturbed by sudden high pings. Here is an example:

```
ping -i 20 google.com
PING google.com (173.194.65.139) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=17.8 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=3 ttl=49 time=20.3 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=4 ttl=49 time=18.2 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=5 ttl=49 time=16.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=6 ttl=49 time=31.1 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=7 ttl=49 time=17.8 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=8 ttl=49 time=17.2 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=9 ttl=49 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=10 ttl=49 time=19.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=11 ttl=49 time=18.4 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=12 ttl=49 **time=245 ms**
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=13 ttl=49 time=17.1 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=14 ttl=49 time=17.8 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=15 ttl=49 time=17.6 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=16 ttl=49 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=17 ttl=49 time=20.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=18 ttl=49 **time=516 ms**
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=19 ttl=49 time=17.5 ms
64 bytes from ee-in-f139.1e100.net (173.194.65.139): icmp_seq=20 ttl=49 time=18.3 ms
```

I have contacted my ISP. They also provided my modem.

How can I make sure the high pings are not caused by a problem with my network card, a driver bug or something client side, something caused by me?

I already tried other networks and there I do not have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an ISP network problem, you can try using tracepath, it shows you all the network segments.

Usually it is used for MTU measurement, but it contains the RTT of each of the network segments.